# Why the ONVIF Subscribe method does not work?

Tags: android, soap, onvif

Trying to implement onvif client on Android to work with IP camera.
I.m want to implemet Event Subscription using WS-Subscription.
For some purposes my request provide correct response, but my server do not recive any messages. Look on my requests below.

==== REQUEST ====

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/bw-2/NotificationProducer/SubscribeRequest</a:Action>
        <a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://192.168.0.239:8080/onvif/events</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Subscribe
            xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2">
            <ConsumerReference>
                <a:Address>
                    http://192.168.0.247:9090/subscription-1
                </a:Address>
            </ConsumerReference>
            <InitialTerminationTime>
                PT60S
                </InitialTerminationTime>
            </Subscribe>
        </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
            <tet:Timeout>PT1M</tet:Timeout>
            <tet:MessageLimit>10</tet:MessageLimit>
        </tet:PullMessages>
    </e:Body>
</e:Envelope>
```

==== RESPONSE ====

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
...>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsa5:ReplyTo SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">
            <wsa5:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa5:Address>
        </wsa5:ReplyTo>
        <wsa5:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://192.168.0.239:8080/onvif/events</wsa5:To>
        <wsa5:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/bw-2/NotificationProducer/SubscribeResponse</wsa5:Action>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <wsnt:SubscribeResponse>
            <wsnt:SubscriptionReference>
                <wsa5:Address>http://192.168.0.239:8080/onvif/Subscription?Idx=0</wsa5:Address>
            </wsnt:SubscriptionReference>
            <wsnt:CurrentTime>2018-06-20T10:16:22Z</wsnt:CurrentTime>
            <wsnt:TerminationTime>2018-06-20T10:17:22Z</wsnt:TerminationTime>
        </wsnt:SubscribeResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

==== SERVER ====

```
class SimpleWebServer @Throws(IOException::class)
constructor() : NanoHTTPD(9090) {

    override fun serve(session: IHTTPSession): Response {
        val data = HashMap<String, String>()
        val method = session.method
        session.parseBody(data)
        // get the POST body
        val postBody = session.getQueryParameterString()
        // or you can access the POST request's parameters
        val postParameter = session.getParms()["parameter"]
        Log.d("SimpleWebServer", "$method : $postBody")

        return NanoHTTPD.newFixedLengthResponse("").also { response response.status = Response.Status.ACCEPTED } // Or postParameter.
    }
}
```

Comment: Also will be happy  if somene know any good instructions how to use Notification Streaming Interface (metadata streaming)

Answer (score 0):

You XML requests seem not be correct. The [ONVIF core specs](https://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification-v1712.pdf) give in §9.10 an example about how to subsribe to events. It's a lot of XML, it is not worth copying it here. Basically what you have to do is this list of tasks:

1. Invoke `GetEventPropertiesRequest` to the the list of supported events (§9.10.1)
2. Call `CreatePullPointSubscription` to create a PullPoint (§9.10.3)
3. Get the events by calling `PullMessages` (§9.10.5)
4. Optionally `Renew` the pull point and/or `Unsubscribe` from it.

For instructions about how to use Notification Streaming Interface, check §7.6 of the [ONVIF Application Programming Guide](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf)

Comment: Thx for your answer!) But I'm have no problems with implementing  PullPointSubscription method. But seems this one does not supported by camera.

And when I'm use **OnvifDeviceMngr Desktop App** I see that events working with **Basic Notification Interface (WS-BaseNotification)** [From ONVIF Application Programming Guide §9)](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf) 

P.S. readed most of specs already, and if it possible want to find some examples)

Comment: And requests I'm using exactly the same as in desktop app.